# What are the dangers of using js prompt for password value in Phonegap (or similar) enviroment

Tags: javascript, forms, cordova, passwords, password-protection

I wondered if using a js prompt to take a password value from the user and place it in a form field has many/any dangers?

I know I could use a modal or something similar, but I just wondered what the consequences could be (other than it may feel strange to a user) bearing in mind the app is installed as native through Phonegap (if it makes a difference).

Comment: A prompt is actually more secure than a modal (I think).

Comment: A window.prompt() could be more secure than a home grown modal simply because there is less to hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues if you are referring to the `window.prompt(message,default);` JS prompt.

1.) On the desktop IE's support is weak - it doesn't support all character sets, the message size is limited, doesn't center properly, and the dialog is beyond ugly. (Bug Info [link1](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/10/bug-109-javascript-prompt-in-ie-how-did.html), [link2](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2008/02/bug-139-javascript-dialogs-dont-center.html))

2.) On Windows 8, in the "Metro Mode" browser, `window.prompt` is defined, but attempting to call it completely fails (the browser just ignores it) and the variable you were hoping to populate gets a `null` value assigned

Since #2 **may** affect Windows 8 Phones (I'm not sure how much of the code base is ported directly for the phones) you'll want to be aware of this potential incompatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm not supporting IE or WP but its good to know. fyi all of the code is just for phone (android and ios).

Comment: was it the default built in `prompt();` method? or are you calling something specific? (e.g. a jQuery UI dialog or something)